# how to use sql with LINQ

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have the asp.net web application in C# language with framework 3.5. I have also sql server database . I want to use sql to Linq concept for insert, update, delete and select the records as well as maintain the transaction like commit and rollback . How to achieve this ?

Comment: There are plenty of LINQ to SQL tutorials and books around. Stack Overflow isn't really good for this sort of question - it's much better for *specific* questions.

Comment: okai... but i want to know basics important topics. what i have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the following [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx). That will walk you through the basic concepts and ideas behind the framework. Following that if you have any questions feel free to post a more direct question somewhere here.

Happy coding!